# "Object expected" error with "javascript:ShowDocument" statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I added code to one button but while clicking it raises "Object expected" Javascript error

`Me.btnReport.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Concat(New String() {"Javascript:ShowDocument('frmDocReport.aspx?PrjId=", Me.droplstProject.SelectedItem.Value, "&Type=", Me.droplstType.SelectedItem.Value, "&RecPerPage=", Me.droplstPAGE.SelectedItem.Value, "&DocNo=", Me.txtSearch.Text, "')"}))`

I think its simple but I am not able to solve

In my view source I can see like this

```
onclick="Javascript:ShowDocument('frmDocReport.aspx?PrjId=48&amp;Type=0&amp;RecPerPage=5&amp;DocNo=');"
```

Comment: So when you view-source your page, do you have a function ShowDocument ?
And should this not be this.options[this.selectedIndex].value and so on rather than Me.

Comment: or even better: Me.btnReport.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ShowDocument(this))" and do the other stuff in ShowDocument

Comment: In view source i can see onclick="Javascript:ShowDocument('frmDocReport.aspx?PrjId=48&amp;Type=0&amp;RecPerPage=5&amp;DocNo=');"

Comment: And do you see function Showdocument(...) too ?

Comment: Isn't ShowDocument(..) a built in function to open the URLs in new window?

Answer (score 0):

One of the JS objects you are using is null or does not exist.  It is not possible to tell from the code snippet which one. Use a javascript debugger such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the values and work out what is null.  From that you should then be able to work back to why that value is null and solve the error.